# How can I extract just the elements I want from a Perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl

Hey I'm wondering how I can get this code to work. Basically I want to keep the lines of `$filename` as long as they contain the `$user` in the path:

```
        open STDERR, ">/dev/null";
        $filename=`find -H /home | grep $file`;
        @filenames = split(/\n/, $filename);
        for $i (@filenames) {
            if ($i =~ m/$user/) {
                #keep results
            } else {
                delete  $i; # does not work.    
            }
        }
        $filename = join ("\n", @filenames);
        close STDERR;
```

I know you can delete like `delete $array[index]` but I don't have an index with this kind of loop that I know of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could replace your loop with:

```
@filenames = grep /$user/, @filenames;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do it when you're using `foreach` loop. But nevermind. The right thing to do is to use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) to accomplish your task.

```
use File::Find 'find';

...

my @files;
my $wanted = sub {
    return unless /\Q$file/ && /\Q$user/;
    push @files, $_;
};

find({ wanted => $wanted, no_chdir => 1 }, '/home');
```

Don't forget to escape your variables with `\Q` for use in regular expressions.

BTW, redirecting your STDERR to `/dev/null` is better written as

```
{
    local *STDERR;
    open STDERR, '>', '/dev/null';
    ...
}
```

It restores the filehandle after exiting the block.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `find` that supports `-path`, then make it do the work for you, *e.g.*,

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $user = "gbacon";
my $file = "bash";

my $path = join " -a " => map "-path '*$_*'", $user, $file;
chomp(my @filenames = `find -H /home $path 2>/dev/null`);

print map "$_\n", @filenames;
```

Note how backticks in list context give back a list of lines (including their terminators, removed above with `chomp`) from the command's output. This saves you having to `split` them yourself.

Output:

```
/home/gbacon/.bash_history
/home/gbacon/.bashrc
/home/gbacon/.bash_logout
```

Comment: Could you explain what the my $path line is doing? sorry, bit of a noob.

Comment: No problem! Fully expanded, the command becomes `find -H /home -path '*gbacon*' -a -path '*bash*' 2>/dev/null`, that is, everything under `/home` that contains both `gbacon` and `bash` (the `-a` option means 'and' with `find`) somewhere in its path. The trailing `2>/dev/null` discards any error output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove an item from an array, use the multi-talented [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) function.

```
my @foo = qw( a b c d e f );

splice( @foo, 3, 1 ); # Remove element at index 3.
```

You can do all sorts of other manipulations with `splice`.  See the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) for more info.

---

As codeholic alludes to, you should **never** modify an array while iterating over it with a `for` loop.  If you want to modify an array while iterating, use a `while` loop instead.

The reason for this is that `for` evaluates the expression in parens once, and maps each item in the result list to an alias.  If the array changes, the pointers get screwed up and chaos will follow.

A `while` evaluates the condition each time through the loop, so you won't run into issues with pointers to non-existent values.

Comment: Ah okay, It seemed awkward to try it with that loop anyway.